# Hide/Show DIV on KeyPress Not Working jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Confused as to why jQuery is understanding my logic but not functioning off the `show()` and `hide()` on selected DIVs on keypress (yet works to `hide()` on page load).

Here's the script which is at the end of my PHP page.

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){

        $("#resultset_2").hide();
        $("#resultset_3").hide();

// this is working -- `#resultset_2` and `#resultset_3`
// are both set to "display:none;" on page load

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {

    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
      arrow = {left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };

    switch (keyCode) {
    case arrow.left:
      // tbd
    break;
    case arrow.up:
      // tbd
    break;
    case arrow.right:
      // tbd
    break;

    case arrow.down:

    if($('#resultset_1').is(':visible')){

        alert('visible');
        $("#resultset_1").hide();
        $("#resultset_2").show();

    }

    if($('#resultset_2').is(':visible')){

        $("#resultset_2").hide();
        $("#resultset_3").show();

    }
    if($('#resultset_3').is(':visible')){

        $("#resultset_3").hide();
        $("#resultset_1").show();

    }
    break;
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Keypress functionality is working, so I know that's not an issue. When I press `down` on my keyboard I get the alert `'visible'` pop-up indicating that `$resultset_1` is visible.

But nothing happens after that, jQuery ignores the `$("#resultset_1").hide();` and `$("#resultset_2").show();` in my condition.

I've tried variations, such as

```
   if($('#resultset_1').is(':visible')){
        alert('visible');
        $('#resultset_1').css('display','none');
    }
```

With the same result (an alert but an ignore on the div change)

Why is this not functioning properly and how do I fix it to work as defined?
Working with a minified `jQuery v3.3.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `if` statement with your alert you unhide `#resultset_2` and therefore the second `if` statement executes and `#resultset_2` is hidden once again and `#resultset_3` is shown. The same thing happens with the next `if` statement, hiding `#resultset_3` and showing `#resultset_1` again. You should make the second two `if` statements `else if` statements.

Comment: Ay! I guess my logic was wrong :) Makes sense.  Enacted the change and is now functioning properly, will accept in a few minutes!